# Adding factor levels when using rows_append()

Tags: r, dplyr, append

When I'm using `rows_append()` how do I add the levels of my additional data to prevent this error: `Error in rows_append():! Can't convert from...`

I would like the end result to include all levels in the newly combined data set.

Here's a reprex

```r
library(dplyr)

data1 <- iris[1:100,] %>%
  droplevels()
data2 <- iris[101:150,] %>%
  droplevels()

dataFull <- data1 %>%
  rows_append(data2)
#> Error in `rows_append()`:
#> ! Can't convert from `y$Species` <factor<23909>> to `x$Species` <factor<44a85>> due to loss of generality.
```

Comment: use `bind_rows(data1, data2)` instead?

Comment: got it! thanks, I hadn't caught onto the difference between bind_rows() and rows_append()

Answer (score 1):

Update removed first answer: (thanks to @Axeman):

We could combine the factor levels and make them consistent across datasets

```
library(dplyr)

levels <- union(levels(data1$Species), levels(data2$Species))

data1$Species <- factor(data1$Species, levels = levels)
data2$Species <- factor(data2$Species, levels = levels)

data1 %>% 
  rows_append(data2) %>% 
  str()

'data.frame':   150 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Sepal.Length: num  5.1 4.9 4.7 4.6 5 5.4 4.6 5 4.4 4.9 ...
 $ Sepal.Width : num  3.5 3 3.2 3.1 3.6 3.9 3.4 3.4 2.9 3.1 ...
 $ Petal.Length: num  1.4 1.4 1.3 1.5 1.4 1.7 1.4 1.5 1.4 1.5 ...
 $ Petal.Width : num  0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2 0.4 0.3 0.2 0.2 0.1 ...
 $ Species     : Factor w/ 3 levels "setosa","versicolor",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: This will lose 1 factor level and generate a bunch on NAs. You'd need e.g. `union(levels(data1$Species), levels(data2$Species))`

Comment: You are right. For me it is not exactly clear where OP wants to end?! your `bind_rows(data1, data2)` is more obvious!

Comment: hmn. almost, but there should be 3 levels altogether for the Species column: setosa, versicolor and virginica,

Comment: thanks for the feedback about clarity @TarJae, I edited my question.

Comment: thanks for the update! do you have any insight into when one might use rows_append() as opposed to bind_rows()?

Comment: `rows_append` has its power in manipulating individual rows <https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/rows.html>, whereas `bind_rows` is more to efficiently bind multiple data frames by row <https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind.html>